# Install plugin in Netbeans platform

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-platform

We're developing an application on the netbeans platform. In that application, we don't need the plugin center (yet) so we haven't enabled the modules needed for the plugin center.

But now we want to install a 3rd party plugin into our application. The plugin in question is beanmill, http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/4702/beanmill-logging-viewer-log4j-jsr47, which we use to view logmessages. Is it possible to do this without the plugin center? And if it is, how would we do that? Either programmatically or on the commandline would be preferable.

Anything that could shed some light on the matter would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think [Can I bundle some additional files with my module?](http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqInstalledFileLocator) and then [How can I run the installer for something else during module installation?](http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqUseNativeInstaller) will help you do what you want.